# Designer Pattern para Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, design-pattern

Galera, alguém conhece um bom livro, apostila, ou blog que explique bem sobre Designer Pattern, especializado em Objective-C/iOS, com bons exemplos e atualizados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma excelente referência online sobre design patterns em Objective-C usando iOS como plataforma: http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Já a Apple tem um [guia inicial bem](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/StreamlineYourAppswithDesignPatterns/StreamlineYourApps/StreamlineYourApps.html) rapido de ler, abordando os principais design patterns utilizados no iOS.

Comment: Eu ja estou estudando esse link do Ray, mas estava atras de algo em portugues brasil.